# odd behaviours from template tags

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, templates, page-template, template-tags

Some of my template tags are playing up, and they have left me confused.

On one site, that has been live for over a year without any of these issues, on all the pages that have custom query loops, `the_content()` was repeating the first entry. I replaced that line with `echo get_the_cotent($post->ID)`, which I thought was totally equivalent, and it solved the problem.

Now, I have a very similar issue with another site. Trying to fetch and display content from child pages, I have this code block:

```
global $post;
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));
$children = get_page_children($post->ID,$all_wp_pages);
foreach($children as $child){

    ?>
    <div class="childPage">
    <h3><?php the_title($child->ID); ?></h3>
    </div>  
    <?php
}
```

but this just repeats the title of the parent page.

However, if I replace `the_title` with `echo get_the_title(` is works as expected.

I am only *assuming* these are comparable issues, the certainly have similar symptoms and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Post ID is **not** an argument in `the_title()` ([see Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)). Accepted arguments are:

```
the_title( $before, $after, $echo );
```

Take a look at the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L33). The function `the_title()` calls `get_the_title()` with no arguments, whereas `get_the_title()` takes a Post ID as its *only* argument. If you want the title of a post/page other than the current one in the query, stick with `echo get_the_title(...`.

**Edit:** BTW, Post ID is an argument for neither `the_content()` nor `get_the_content()`.

Comment: It works, though.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz I guess it's because you messed with the global...